# Cannot log in to Server Fault with stack exchange account

Tags: support

My ServerFault account is linked to my StackExchange account, but now there is no option to log in using stackExchange.

How can I log in using stackexchange account?

[image: Server Fault log in page]

Comment: Try entering the openid endpoint manually? https://openid.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you tried filling in your Stack Exchange OpenID credentials in the *Email*  and *Password* fields?

Comment: Still a problem

Comment: still a problem 2024. @user247702 [OpenID is no longer supported on SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ended-on-july-25-2018). Do you have any suggestions how to come around the issue today?